# How to print columns which are coming from data dataprovider in listing uiComponent

Tags: magento2

I want to print the columns on screen which are fetched from dataprovider for my listing uiComponent. So where can i print those columns? Like in which php file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you want to print?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I want to print it on my custom listing page to know how many columns i am getting from dataprovider.

Comment: So you want to print one table column in another table listing page. right?

Comment: No actually i want to know how many columns dataprovider is providing for listing of specific table. So i want to print those columns to browser before it display in table.
Let say I have custom table with name "test" now i have created listing uiComponent to display those columns in grid view. Now after fetching and before displaying those to table i want to see which are the columns i am getting.

Comment: Please put a log in the Model `Collection.php` file. You can see there which columns are you getting.